# Recreating Google Maps API for Android

Tags: android, api, google-maps, key

I have an android application that is on Google Play right now. It uses Google Maps v2 to display maps so it has an API Key. But another developer who has worked before me, used his own gmail account to create the API Project. So I created a new API Project with my own gmail account but I wonder that when I publish the app will it work with new API Key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, your key will work, if you have generated it correctly. But you have to upload new version of app (with new key).

Comment: Thanks. I created a new debug key and it works. So you're right, I guess it will work when i create a release api key and publish the app with it.

Comment: Yes, generate release key again for publishing. You must know SHA for release key will be different, you can get that using keystore which you generated during signing you apk